# How to write correctly jinja2 template using for loop ,

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

I have the following dataframe, that came from some query :

```
SYS   ID          TYPE          Number
SAP IX_sys  IX_sys_daily_FICO   83646
SAP IX_sys  IX_sys_daily_FICO   326
SAP IX_sys  IX_sys_daily_FICO    19
SAP IX_sys  IX_sys_daily_FICO   628
SAP IX_sys  IX_sys_daily_FICO   574
SAP IX_sys  IX_sys_daily_FICO   623
```

what I did  in python code  is :

```
first = df_ora['SYS']
second = df_ora['ID']
Third=df_ora['TYPE']
Four=df_ora['Number']
```

and i passed to the template jinja2 like :

```
<tbody>
  {% for i in first %}
    <tr class="table-active">
    
        <td>{{ i}}</td>
    </tr>
        {% endfor %}


  </tbody>
```

this gave me first column just :

```
SAP
SAP
SAP
SAP
SAP
SAP
```

How i can pass all the values to be like what is desired :

```
SYS   ID          TYPE          Number
SAP IX_sys  IX_sys_daily_FICO   83646
SAP IX_sys  IX_sys_daily_FICO   326
SAP IX_sys  IX_sys_daily_FICO    19
SAP IX_sys  IX_sys_daily_FICO   628
SAP IX_sys  IX_sys_daily_FICO   574
SAP IX_sys  IX_sys_daily_FICO   623
```

any idea , Big thanks for anyone can help me .

Comment: All column items are SAP, so this is the expected ouptut, isn't it?

Comment: no ... actaully i need to extend the table and have the same like what is desired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<tbody>
  {% for i in range(0,first|length) %}
    <tr class="table-active">       
        <td>{{ first[i]}}</td>
        <td>{{ second[i]}}</td>
        <td>{{ Third[i]}}</td>
        <td>{{ Four[i]}}</td>
    </tr>
        {% endfor %}


  </tbody>
```

Comment: ` {% for i in first|length %}
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable `

Comment: What a Gold Person you are , Thank you alot , it is work Perfectly :)

Comment: For Sure Mate :)